# Respondendo a própria pergunta

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Eae galera, eu tava navegando no SOpt quando vi uma pergunta qual a resposta era muito simples, mas mesmo assim fiquei curioso, ao entrar na pergunta vi quando ela havia sido publicada , estava escrito a 5min atrás, logo abaixo eu vi uma resposta, por acaso correta mas a resposta colocada era do próprio dono da pergunta e ele tinha postado logo após ter perguntado, e tentando se passar por outra pessoa na resposta como se ele já estivesse preparado para avaliar sua própria resposta como certa, bom mesmo assim não falei nada e respondi, esperando ganhar o voto de certo porém nada ainda, eu não sei suas intenções e não estou aqui para julgar ninguém, bom só queria saber a opnião de vocês sobre esse assunto e se isso já aconteceu antes.
Pergunta:  [Como atualizar funcionário especifico em tabela no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128918/como-atualizar-funcion%C3%A1rio-especifico-em-tabela-no-mysql/128943#128943)

Comment: Você não pesquisou sobre isso aqui no meta ;)

[Responder sua própria pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta) e [Respondi minha própria pergunta, fiz algo errado?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37/respondi-minha-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta-fiz-algo-errado)

Comment: é eu realmente não tinha visto esse post, mas eu ainda sim gostaria que vocês avaliassem a pergunta que eu citei a cima pois ele não só respondeu a própria pergunta como também da para ver obviamente que ele não tinha dúvidas sobre esse assunto, no casa foi totalmente desnecessário esse post

Comment: Nikk lê os dois links que te deixei, lá responde a isso.

Comment: Você está correto, Obrigado pela resposta @Jorge B.